# Let TeamCity track warnings from IAR-Compiler via command line runner

Tags: teamcity, iar, teamcity-8.0

i am currently working with TeamCity's latest version.
I have configured TeamCity to compile my IAR Embedded Workbench Projects via command line runner as follows:

```
Run: Executable with parameters
Command executable: %IAR_PATH%\common\bin\IarBuild.exe
Command parameters: project1/example_project/_build/example.ewp -build Debug
```

SVN structure is:

```
<root>---- tags
|
+--------- branches
|
+--------- trunk 
           |
           +---- example_project 
                 |
                 +---- _build
```

In order to highlight "todo-notes", i have a function which generates warnings as todo notes which you can see in the compile log. Examples:

```
file_main.cpp(353) : Warning[TODO]: "this should be done tomorrow."
main.cpp(99) : Remark[Ga826]: parameter "foobar" was never referrenced.
debug.cpp(123) : Remark[Pe192]: argument is incompatible with corresponding format string conversion
```

How can i make TeamCity track these warning messages? I want to show them in the Overview-tab, or if its impossible, in an extra warning tab.
I've tried to figure it out with MSBuilder examples and the documentation, but i'm stuck with figuring it out. =/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you say "track these warning messages" I assume you mean just show them and not break the build if it finds them. Correct?

Comment: Well you can fail the build when it finds specific build text in the build log but that's not going to help in that case. I'm not aware of a way to simply highlight the text.

Comment: Mhm.. i hope that there's an option to display something like this:
Build success, but there where some warnings: warning1, warning2, ..

Comment: So your function, does it generate a log file which has just warnings or it adds warnings in the same log file.

Comment: It adds warning in the same log file - just like normal warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows. I wrote two simple parser programs in Python:

A **buildlog parser** to get the current build-log snippet which contains the IAR-log and an **IAR-log parser** which uses regular expressions. Seems a bit complicated and there is maybe a simpler way to do this, but it works!